# How to obtain the closest mean distance between two pseudoparallel lines

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator, average, closest-distance

From two layers (LINE_1 and LINE_2) with a irregular pseudoparallel lines geometry, my goal is to obtain the closest mean distance between two pseudoparallel lines.

Here I publish a screenshot with the workspace approach

[image]

My initial idea is to do the calculation by dividing the line into a set of points. Then my goal would be to develop a single expression that integrates functions like `shortest_line`, `length` and `mean`, to obtain the average closest distance between the points of the second line.

Here is a representation of what I am looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both solutions will only work correctly when you use the same projected CRS on both line layers.

**Solution A: Distance to the closest points on the second line:**

```sql
array_mean(
  array_foreach(
    array_foreach(
      generate_series(0,length($geometry),10),
      line_interpolate_point($geometry,@element)
    ),
  distance(aggregate('line1','collect',$geometry),@element)
  )
)
```

What it does:

1. Create distances along the line by using `generate_series()`
2. Create interpolated points at these distances by using `line_interpolate_point()`
3. Iterate over these points via `array_foreach()` and get the `distance()` to the second line by using `aggregate()` or some different function to get another line. `distance()` `Returns the minimum distance (based on spatial reference) between two geometries in projected units.`
4. At this point you have an array of the closest distances. Build the mean value using `array_mean()`.

Discussion:

The expression is much easier to implement and to understand, but it has one great disadvantage: It always measures the length to the closest point on the other line. As you can see in the screenshot below, this may not accurate for some usecases. However, it should work without issuses on very curvy lines, changing their main angle often, as well.

Visualized:

[image]

Expression for visualization:

```sql
collect_geometries(
  array_foreach(
    array_foreach(
      generate_series(0,length($geometry),10),
      line_interpolate_point($geometry,@element)
    ),
  make_line(closest_point(aggregate('line1','collect',$geometry),@element),@element)
  )
)
```

**Solution B: Distance to line in a specified angle:**

```sql
array_mean(
array_remove_all(
  array_foreach(
    array_foreach(
      generate_series(0,length($geometry),10),
      line_interpolate_point($geometry,@element)
    ),
  length(make_line(intersection(
    aggregate('line1','collect',$geometry),
    make_line(project(@element,9999,radians(main_angle($geometry)+90)),@element)
  ),@element))
  ),
NULL)
)
```

What it does:

1. Create distances along the line by using `generate_series()`
2. Create interpolated points at these distances by using `line_interpolate_point()`
3. Iterate over these points via `array_foreach()` and
4. Create a line with a pseudo length of `9999`m (change this value to your needs) in
5. a specified angle. Here we use the main angle of the line `+90°`, we get via `main_angle()`. You may need to change `+90` to `-90` or something different, depending on your geometries and your personal needs.
6. Now we need to find the intersection of these lines to the second line. We can get it via `intersection()`.
7. To prevent an invalid result, we can remove all invalid geometries by using `array_remove_all()` to remove all `NULL` values.
8. Finally we construct a line via `make_line()` from the points from `generate_series()` to the points from `intersection()`
9. Get the `length()` of these lines
10. At this point you have an array of the line lengts. Build the mean value using `array_mean()`.

Discussion:

The expression is a little more difficult to understand and implement, but it has one great advantage over solution A: It always measures the length to the other line in the same angle. However, this may be tricky to implement, if you have curvy lines changing their main angle a lot. In this case, I can suggest to split the line into different features and instead of using `aggregate()` to get the second layers line, you may use `get_feature()` together with `geometry()`, to get only one specific, related line.

Visualized:

[image]

Expression for visualization:

```sql
collect_geometries(
array_remove_all(
  array_foreach(
    array_foreach(
      generate_series(0,length($geometry),10),
      line_interpolate_point($geometry,@element)
    ),
  make_line(intersection(
    aggregate('line1','collect',$geometry),
    make_line(project(@element,9999,radians(main_angle($geometry)+90)),@element)
  ),@element)
  ),
NULL)
)
```

Comment: @IngridIngravida, I have added a second solution with a different method.

Comment: Very clarifying and exactly what I was looking for to get the value